# Looking list of duplicate for columns

Tags: sql

i have a table with this data

Name, id, alt, then col 4, col 5, col6 etc..

i want to list where Name, id, and alt are duplicate other cols can be different. i dont want distinct I do want to know where are dupes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause, as follows:

```
SELECT Name, id, alt, count(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Name, id, alt
HAVING count(*) > 1
```